# Rspec test keeps failing when passing in a named parameter

Tags: ruby, rspec

Sorry in advance....noob question.

I am writing a class to satisfy an Rspec test. It's a test to initialize a class and pass in a string parameter.
My challenge is that the test is passing in a name parameter, and the output keeps failing my test.

Code Below.

My class

```
module Human
  class Person
    attr_reader :name

    def initialize(name)
       @name = name
    end
  end
end
```

My Test

```
RSpec.describe Person::Name do
  subject { described_class.new(name: "Hi my name is peter") }

  it "has a name" do
    expect(subject.name).to eq("Hi my name is peter")
  end
```

The Result

```
Human::Person has a name
     Failure/Error: expect(subject.name).to eq("Hi my name is peter")

       expected: "Hi my name is peter"
            got: {:name=>"Hi my name is peter"}

       (compared using ==)
```

My problem is my class is working, but my output is formatted differently `{:name=>"Hi my name is peter"}`....it should be`"Hi my name is peter"`

How do I get my class to return the string output as expected by my test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test expects that your `new` method accepts a hash with a `name` key and a value. The class is not initialized with just a name.

But in your class, you take all the arguments (key plus value) and assign it to the `@name` variable.

The easiest way to makes this test pass is to used keyword arguments in your `initialize`method.

Change

```
def initialize(name)
```

to

```
def initialize(name:)
```

Read more about [kwags - keyword arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments).

Comment: Thank you so much @spickermann. This make a tonnes more sense now.